# Fully embedded SymPy+Matplotlib+others within a C/C++ application

Tags: python, embed, sympy, pyinstaller

I've read the Python [documentation chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) explaining how to embed the Python interpreter in a C/C++ application. Also, I've read that you can install Python modules either in a system-wide fashion, or locally to a given user.

But let's suppose my C/C++ application will use some Python modules such as SymPy, Matplotlib, and other related modules. And let's suppose end users of my application won't have any kind of Python installation in their machines.

This means that my application needs to ship with "pseudo-installed" modules, inside its data directories (just like the application has a folder for icons and other resources, it will need to have a directory for Python modules).

Another requirement is that the absolute path of my application installation isn't fixed: the user can "drag" the application bundle to another directory and it will run fine there (it already works this way but that's prior to embedding Python in it, and I wish it continues being this way after embedding Python).

I guess my question could be expressed more concisely as "how can I use Python without installing Python, neither system-wide, nor user-wide?"

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you could attempt to do this, but none of them are general solutions. From the ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#embedding-python-in-c)):

> **5.5. Embedding Python in C++**
>
> It is also possible to embed Python in a C++ program; precisely how this is done will depend on the details of the C++ system used; in general you will need to write the main program in C++, and use the C++ compiler to compile and link your program. There is no need to recompile Python itself using C++.

This is the shortest section in the document, and is roughly equivalent to: *'left as an exercise for the reader`*. I do not believe you will find any straight forward solutions.

**Use pyinstaller to gather the pieces:**

> This means that my application needs to ship with "pseudo-installed" modules, inside its data directories (just like the application has a folder for icons and other resources, it will need to have a directory for Python modules).

If I needed to tackle this problem, I would use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) as a base. (Disclosure: I am an occasional contributer). One of the major functions of [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is to gather up all of the needed resources for a python program.  In [onedir](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-folder) mode, all of the things needed to let the program run are gathered into one directory.

You could include this tool into your make system, and have it place all of the needed pieces into your `python` data directory in your build tree.